# Change masterpage of a sub-site automatically, for multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, sub-site, feature-stapling

I am working in an environment which has more than 1000 site collections. My requirement is that when I create a new subsite in any of the site collection, it should automatically inherit masterpage from the parent / set masterpage to a specific one.

I tried to do it using `WebProvisioned` method, also `feature stapler` but none worked or it can be that I am using wrong approach.

Can anyone please suggest me the best approach for this issue?

Comment: Are you really working with SharePoint online, as your question was tagged? If so, how have you tried feature stappling? Handling the WebProvisioned event should do the job. Have you tested, if your event receiver code is executed, and do you have an exception there, or it is not called at all? I assume you registered a remote event receiver, if you are really working with SPO.

Comment: Agreed, can you please provide additional details on the environment you are operating within? Is it SharePoint Online? SharePoint 2010? SharePoint 2013? Standard? Foundation?

Comment: I had tried in development server all the custom codes. If i can get the code working on dev server i can go ahead with Microsoft deployement process. Using `WebProvisioned` , i was unable to deploy the solution with scope as `WebApplication` level. With scope set to `site` and `web`, i could see the solution only in current site collection. Any suggestions?